# Will Thunderbolt noticably change virtual machine performance for an external hard disk drive?

Tags: external-hard-drive, thunderbolt

I've previously read suggestions for [running a virtual machine from an external hard drive](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/VirtualMachinesAndExternalHardDriveThroughput.aspx) to increase performance.  With this in mind, I'm curious what the introduction of a new technology like [Thunderbolt](http://www.apple.com/thunderbolt/) will do to this.

I know that it can't hurt performance, but I'm curious about this -- as slow as hard disk drives are (perhaps [~100 or 200 MBps?](http://www.pctechguide.com/31HardDisk_Performance.htm)), how noticeable of a performance difference could there be for operating a virtual machine?  If USB (even 2.0) transfers faster than the disk can transfer, isn't the bottleneck already the hard drive?

Note:  I know that solid-state drives introduce an entirely new situation; I'm not referring to them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hard disks have best case sustained transfer rates in the 100M **byte** per second ballpark. The best SSDs are in the 500Mbyte/s range (last time I looked).

USB 2.0 specs at a *theoretical* 480M **bit** per second. Serial schemes usually do some kind of bit-to-byte encoding, like [8b/10b](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8b/10b_encoding) or [NRZI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-Return-to-Zero_Inverted#Non-Return-to-Zero_Inverted_(NRZI)) with bit-stuffing. So to convert the speeds, you can make it easy on yourself and just divide bits by 10 to get bytes.

USB's real-world performance is well below theoretical. Some hard disks can definitely saturate USB 2 (at least some of the time). Some SSDs can probably saturate USB 3. Thunderbolt is at least twice as fast as USB 3, and does not suffer from host overhead; it currently has headroom for single drives of either variety.

Is the difference noticeable? If you have a fast enough hard drive and run it on USB 2, you should be able to tell if you switch to Thunderbolt -- for some workloads.

As for virtualization, no specific extra advantages come to mind, although improvements like [VT-d](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_VT-d#I.2FO_MMU_virtualization_.28AMD-Vi_and_VT-d.29) or its successors might work better with Thunderbolt.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever the slowest device is in a chain of devices involved in transferring data, that is your bottleneck.

Intel's Thunderbolt technology promises 10 Gbps transfer rates:  http://www.intel.com/technology/io/thunderbolt/

Answer (score 0):

Since it is basically a external PCIe bus with multiple channels full duplex and chaining capability, I would say hell yea. Hook a 24 bay external raid enclosure without having to pay a 10gbps ethernet of fiber channel tax is going to make a big difference.